# Angular 5 - Images do not load after being uploaded to the disk storage

Tags: angular, image, express, multer, kinvey

I have an Angular project for sharing photos. When I upload pictures everything works well - they are uploaded to the **assets/images/uploads**, which is said to be a public folder. Images are being uploaded with multer, using a simple Express server. I also use Kinvey to save some data for the images and I also save their filenames.

After I upload the images and I go to the page with all of the images, they are not being loaded. **Note that** the path to the image is correctly set at the image src tag.

When I rebuild the app, restart the server and refresh the page, all of the images load correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The assets folder is part of the angular build process, and is not meant for dynamic content. You probably need to find another place where users can upload images to.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically update the folder or should I store the images outside the Angular app folder?

Comment: You should be storing your images on the server, not on the client (i.e. in the `app` folder). e.g. A pretty common practice is to store the images on a server (whether it be your web-server, an S3 insatnce, or some CDN) and then save the location/path to those images in your DB.